# "Load more comments" button -> prevent loading duplicates due to changes in database

Tags: mysql

I am coding an app where users can read and write comments.

When the number of comments exceed a certain limit, a "Load more coments" button is displayed and the offset of loaded comments is stored.

I update this offset whenever the user writes or deletes own comments so that no duplicates are loaded and no comments are left out.

But I forgot about the case when the database changes because other users added/deleted comments.

So the offset method seems to be unreliable, so is there any way to solve this problem maybe by saving the id of the last comment and using this as some kind of "offset"?

The WHERE clause in my query is like:

`WHERE x = ? ORDER BY y = ?` (neither x nor y are the ID, y is not unique)

Comment: Add a timestamp column use it as the reference.

Comment: I have an indexed timestamp column, but how can I use this? The timestamp column is not unique by its nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a timestamp column or possibly even the primary key itself depending on how you've set that up. Here is an example of using the primary key if it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer.

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `comment_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `thread_id` int NOT NULL, 
    `comment` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`thread_id`) REFERENCES `threads` (`thread_id`)
);
```

In that table definition, you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `int` primary key. You also have a `thread_id` that is a foreign key to a `threads` table. Finally, you have the comment itself in `comment`.

When you first load the page for some thread you'd do the following:

```
SELECT comment_id, comment 
FROM comments 
WHERE thread_id = 123 
ORDER BY comment_id
LIMIT 10;
```

This means you'd select 10 comments ordered by their `int` PK for your given thread (`123` in this case). Now, when you display this, you need to somehow save the largest `comment_id`. Say in this case it is `10`. Then, have the "Load more comments" button pass this largest `comment_id` to the server when it is clicked. The server will now execute the following:

```
SELECT comment_id, comment
FROM comments
WHERE thread_id = 123 AND comment_id > 10 -- 10 is the value you passed in as your largest previously loaded comment_id
ORDER BY comment_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Now you have a set of ten more comments where you know that none of the comments can possibly be duplicates of your previously displayed comments, and you will never skip over any comments because they're always ordered by ascending `int` keys.

If you now look back to the query you used for loading the initial set of comments, you'll see that it's pretty much the same as the one for loading additional comments, so you can actually use the same query for both. When you load the comments initially just pass `0` as the largest `comment_id`.

You can do the same thing using a `timestamp` column as well if you don't have a primary key that works like this, and you don't want to change it to work like this either. You'd simply order the results by the `timestamp` column, and then pass the `timestamp` of the last loaded comment to your "Load more comments" function. In order to avoid skipping comments posted at the same time, you can use a `timestamp` with six digits of fractional second precision. Create the `timestamp` column as `TIMESTAMP(6)`. Your timestamps will then be recorded as things like `2014-09-08 17:51:04.123456`, where the last six digits after the second are the fraction of a second. With this much precision, it's extremely unlikely that you have comments recorded exactly at the same time.

Of course you could still have two or more comments recorded at the same exact timestamp, but it's unlikely. This makes the `AUTO_INCREMENT` `int` a slightly better solution. One final option is to use a time-based `UUID` because they include a mechanism to ensure uniqueness by slightly adjusting the value when things occur at the same microsecond. They are also still ordered by time. The problem with this is that MySQL does not have very good support for UUIDs.

Comment: The problem with using the timestamp as a filter is, that two or more comments can have the same timestamp value.

Comment: You can deal with this problem by using a higher resolution `timestamp`. MySQL gives you timestamps with six digits of fractional second precision: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html 

Updating my answer to detail this as well.

Comment: And I guess due to the time the db needs to insert a row, a higher resolution timestamp is unique per entry? This would be great.

Comment: Is there a special way to SELECT this kind of timestamp? When I look through my table with my MySql client I see the microseconds but when I retrieve the data in a SELECT statement, it is something like `2017-05-21 12:28:43`.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening. How are you inserting the `timestamp`? Are you using the MySQL `now()` function? If so, then you need to do `now(6)`. If you create the table with `your_date timestamp(6)` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and then you insert data using `now(6)` for the date, then when you execute `select(*)` you'll see the microseconds. If this is not the case, please update your original question with your execute table creation sql, and the way you are inserting.

Comment: Everything is working fine, now. I am using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` as the default value for the timestamp column which has the datatype `TIMESTAMP(6)`. When I select the data I use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS timestamp` and I get a unix timestamp with microseconds at the end of it.